# Keyboard is not opening automatically though autoFocus={true}

Tags: android, react-native, keyboard, autofocus

I have a `TextInput` inside a `Modal` with `autoFocus={true}`. As soon as `Modal` is opened `TextInput` is focused automatically but keyboard is not opening automatically.And surprisingly this is happening randomly. sometimes keyboard opens and sometimes not. This is happening in both emulator and real device.

Any suggestions to overcome this behavior? Thank You.

Comment: Did you try giving a reference and calling to `focus()` method from it?

Comment: @firatswhere can we call .focus method from?

Comment: please check my answer below @Mighty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can pass focus to TextInput using reference whenever a Modal is visible

```
<Modal onShow={() => {this.textInput.focus()}} > 
    <TextInput ref={input => {this.textInput = input}} />
</Modal>
```

Comment: Awesome!.It worked for me. But I wonder how come ref of TextInput is available in onShow.because by the time TextInput is not rendered yet.

Comment: Best and only working answer that I found. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem currently. I used the solution suggestes by saumil and others previously; but adjusted for functional components:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
...
let textInput = useRef(null);
<Modal onShow={() => { textInput.focus(); }} ...>
   <TextInput ref={(input) => { textInput = input; }} ... />
</Modal>
```

It works, but I don't quite know what I'm doing (explanations welcomed). It's important to delete the `autoFocus={true}` to get consistent results.

Answer (score 0):

Need to check though,

```
// Keyboard IpM
 InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

// input is TextInputEditText in here.
// adding a listener 
input.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean isFocused) {

        if (isFocused) {
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
        } 
    }
});
```

Comment: May i know where can i check this. Do you want me to paste this code where or is it exists?

Comment: for fragment(Modal/Dialog), use it inside onViewCreated(), for simplicity I have used here TextInputEditText.

Comment: I am unable to get these terminologies as i have never heard of them. is it something to be done in android studio? Can you please let know the path?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `focus` method. Like this;

```
focus() {
   this.textInputRef.focus();
}


render() {
    return (
      <TextInput
        ref={ref => {
          this.textInputRef = ref;
        }}       
      />
    );
}
```

Now you can call `focus` function whenever you want. It will focus on the textinput and open the keyboard immediately.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me. Use **android:focusedByDefault="true"**

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Email">

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:focusedByDefault="true" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: I believe OP is looking for higher-level (React Native) code.